# Which is the correct phrase: "I'm having rest" or "I'm taking rest"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrase-usage

Which one is correct: "I'm having rest" or "I'm taking rest"?

Comment: _I'm having **a** rest_ or _taking a rest_ are more usual.

Comment: or *I'm resting*

Comment: Why are you uncertain about this, Have you done any research?  Have you tried looking for examples of these phrases in a web search? Why do you think they might be wrong?  If you can describe what you have already done, we can answer your question better.

Comment: In future set off examples with quote marks or italics, or else use block quotes please

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in the comments, these constructions are more commonly used:

> I'm having a rest.
> I'm taking a rest.
> I'm resting.

You could also say:

> I'm getting (some) rest.

The following would typically be considered ungrammatical (hence the asterisk*), unless you are saying that you yourself personify rest, or something similarly unusual.

> *I'm rest.

The below is a maybe borderline case (although it's difficult to imagine a native English speaker making the utterance):

> ? I'm having rest.

It would be more typical to say, as noted above, something like:

> I'm getting rest.

Answer (score 0):

Say "I'm resting", I've never used "I'm having a rest" or "I'm taking a rest". Those are probably `literal translations`

Comment: _I'm having a rest_ is quite normal in British English.

Comment: I did not know that. Like friend to friend, Family to Family, or both?

Comment: Any context. There's nothing special about it.

Answer (score -1):

In American English it is common to *take* a rest, a break, a bath, a shower.
In British English, people prefer to *have* a rest, a break, a bath, a shower.

Figures from the GloWbE corpus:

- Take a rest: US 55, UK 77
- Have a rest: US 17, UK 103

Australia and New Zealand have roughly the same proportions as UK. Canada, Ireland, India have a preference for *Take a rest*, but not nearly as strongly as the US.

I have assumed you meant *taking/having **a** rest*, as that is the common phrase in my experience. We can talk about "taking rest" (as an uncountable noun) but it's much less common - except, it appears, in India and nearby countries:

- Taking rest: 95, of which 55 are India, Pakistan, or Bangladesh, and only 7 US or UK.
- Taking a rest: 135, of which 37 US, 17 GB, and only 7 total for India, Pakistan, and Bangladesh.